# Asking a question it doesn't show up right away under 'Questions'.

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am not sure if this is really a bug or not, but right after asking a question it shows up immediately on the home page (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), but takes about a minute before it shows up on the questions tab (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions).

Every time it happens to me my first thought is that maybe I didn't hit the button to ask the question.

Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, due to caching on the server.